# WebView Html Fixed Header Scroll Table

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a Page in Html which has a big Table.

So I want the First Row (Header) and First Column (Header) to be Fixed.

I tried the Solution given in

http://ajaxian.com/archives/freeze-pane-functionality

That scroll well in Chrome, Firefox in windows but it does work with WebView in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by using

[JQuery Fixed Header Table](http://fixedheadertable.com/)

and

[IScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

With JQuery Fixed Header Table i got the Fixed Headers but does not work on Mobile Browsers. So I integrated the Fixed Header and IScroll by making some change in their code. And I got it worked.

Comment: How smooth does it work? Usually a header moves with a delay when using js libraries...

Answer (score 0):

Just add a few lines of CSS in your first row of table

```
.fixed-row
{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
}
```

I hope it is exectly what you want.